# How to pass pathname into web socket and use @DestinationVariable in Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm a fresher level java programmer. I try to make a application and want to use Web Socket, Stomp JS and my config like:

In java:

```
Config:
`@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    //registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws");

  }`

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    //Server send to client who is subscribed with edit
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/edit");

    //Client send to server through method was remarked by @MessageMapping annotation
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }
}

Controller Class:
@Controller
public Mycontroller{
@MessageMapping("/edit")
  @SendTo("/edit")
  public Message recMessage(Message message){
    System.out.println(message.getMessage());

    return new Message("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getMessage()) + "!");
  }
}

const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
  brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws'
});

In front-end, my app.js

`stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => {
  console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
  setConnected(true);
//Subscribe
  `stompClient.subscribe('/edit', (message) => {
    showGreeting(JSON.parse(message.body).message);
  });`
};`
```

I do like example.
My problem is: I want each URL like:
http://localhost:8080/abc.html; http://localhost:8080/def.html, when client browser each URL, I will subscribe each to a channel like: /edit/abc; /edit/def... to communicate between client and server. But I don't know how to do that, I don't know how to transmit abc, def... to server from client.

I try to pass variable but it won't work